# Oracle Insert query is not working & also not throwing any error

Tags: php, oracle, yii

Hi I am new in Oracle .

I am trying to insert a record into a table using oracle in PHP.
But it's not working ,also not throwing any error .

Below is my code .
Please tell me where I am doing wrong .

```
$insertSQL= "INSERT INTO GL_USR_MAIL_FOLDER(FK_GLUSR_USR_ID, GL_USR_MAIL_FOLDER_NAME) VALUES (:USERDET,:FOLDERNAME) RETURNING GL_USR_MAIL_FOLDER_ID INTO :FOLDER_ID";
try{
  //  echo "try 111LL:L";
    $stid = oci_parse($dbh, $insertSQL);
    $e = oci_error($stid);  // For oci_execute errors pass the statement handle
    print htmlentities($e['message']);
}catch (Exception $ex) {
    GlobalFunc::print_oracle_error(__CLASS__, __FILE__, __LINE__, "Parsing of Query couldn't take place ","Parsing of Query couldn't take place for Query : \n $sql", $ex,0);
}
try{
    //echo "try bindd";
    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":USERDET", $postData['glusrid']);
    oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":FOLDERNAME", $postData['foldername']);
     oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":FOLDER_ID", $folderid, 8, OCI_B_INT);
     $e = oci_error($stid);  // For oci_execute errors pass the statement handle
    print htmlentities($e['message']);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    GlobalFunc::print_oracle_error(__CLASS__, __FILE__, __LINE__, "Binding of Query couldn't take place ","Binding of Query couldn't take place for Query : \n $sql", $ex,0);
}
try{
    $s = oci_execute($stid);
    if(!$s){

        $e = oci_error($stid); 
    print htmlentities($e['message']);
    }
    print_r($s);echo "after execute";


    oci_commit($dbh);

}catch(Exception $ex){
    GlobalFunc::print_oracle_error(__CLASS__, __FILE__, __LINE__, "Execution of Query couldn't take place ","Execution of Query couldn't take place for Query : \n $sql", $ex,0);
}
```

Comment: Are you using Yii framework? In that case, have you tried to use ActiveRecord with Php PDO instead direct database access (oci_.....)?